# Javascript JSON parse error: unexpected character @

Tags: jquery, json

I have a web service which response is a JSON object like this:

http://pastebin.com/VMLEw3XW

I'm trying to parse it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.getJSON("url", function (result) {
        var output = $.parseJSON(result);
        var list = output.data;
        $.each(list, function (i, item) {
            console.log(item.city);
        });
    });
```

But i get this error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character @ myapp/js/jquery.js:4

Could anybody please help me, how can I parse this JSON object?

Comment: `$.getJSON` should already be doing the parsing for you. Is it not?

Comment: It's json, the unexpected character is an 'o' for object when trying to parse a javascript object again.

Comment: So my result is my parsed json object?:)

Comment: @solarenqu that's right. Remove the `$.parseJSON()` line.

Comment: Thank you I'm gonna try later :)

Comment: Thank you it's working. But my result varriable is a json array. How can i iterate on it? I have json response like this: http://pastebin.com/5ypBYGez Thank you!